# iOS Receiving Turn Notifications and Updating GameState

Tags: ios, game-center

Do I have to look for updated match state once the "Your Turn" notification is received.

At present when the notification is received, I am opening the game centre with "findMatchWithMinPlayers...." and updating the game state.

And how can one know when its there turn and app is not in background, means no notification is displayed ?

I have gone through many posts, but still a lot of things are not clear to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate = self;`

should be added to all method of `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate`

Reason: Delegate session is losing focus. See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924294/handleturneventformatchdidbecomeactive-callbacks-only-arriving-some-of-the-tim/15383714#15383714)